Tracking Area 51 site stats
This post is intended to keep tracks of our Area 51 stats over time and to see our progress towards graduation. 
For graduation, the rough criteria are :

Mostly green (Excellent) on the stats page
Upward trend in site stats over time

I will try to update it every 20 days, but feel free to do so if I am not able to.
351 Days

248 Days

200 days

190 days

161 days

141 days
Click to view.
120 days
Click to view.
100 days
Click to view.

Time for a Grow-spurt.

Small Note: this subject will never get 15 questions per day on average.

@Stolas Criteria for graduation is mostly green (i.e. even 4/5 will do). The most important ones are number of users and visits/day.

I dont think we should keep more than 5 images within the post. Made changes.

We have reached 2000 users today !

@AsheeshR could be updated again, I don't know which software you used for this.

@heinrich5991 I use Ubuntu so just Shift + Print Screen does the trick.
